# Neighboring property irrespective of continuity.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Given, $f(x,y),g(x,y)$ functions with $f(x,y)\gt g(x,y)\gt 1$, where $(x, y)\in [0,1]\times[0,1]$.

Now, irrespective of continuity of $f(x,y),g(x,y)$, can we say that there is an open ball $B$ about $(1,1)$ such that $\left(g^{-\frac{x+y}{x+xy}}-f^{-\frac{x+y}{y+xy}}\right)-(f-g)\lt0$ for $(x,y)\in B\cap ([0,1]\times[0,1])$?

At $(1,1)$, clearly, $\left(g^{-1}-f^{-1}\right)-(f-g)\lt0$.

Then, without continuity, can I say $\left(g^{-\frac{x+y}{x+xy}}-f^{-\frac{x+y}{y+xy}}\right)-(f-g)\lt0$ is true for $(x,y)\in B\cap ([0,1]\times[0,1])$?

Comment: What here is assumption and what is thesis